# Windows: select default certificate for Enterprise Wifi connection

Tags: certificate

When you have more than 1 Client Authentication certificate in your user certificate store, Windows will prompt on (appropriately configured) wireless connection to allow you to select desired certificate to be used for connection.

In Windows 7, it was possible to save this selection for further use - thus subsequent connections were made with the selected certificate with no prompt. For some reason, Windows 10 doesn't do the same - it will basically prompt every time, and there's no "Save as default" checkbox. Am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't a security question and would fit better on [su].

Comment: Try this update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-are-prompted-to-select-a-certificate-when-you-connect-to-a-wireless-network-in-windows-7-or-in-windows-server-2008-r2-e3774f4b-9fc2-edfb-3429-d7b847100122

Comment: Windows 10 has a concept of WiFi profiles which is not the same as in Windows 7 that's why.